# Slide from right animation when changing rootViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to change my rootViewController with a slide-from-right animation.

I know how to do it with a flip animation:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LandingViewController") 


UIView.transitionWithView( UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!,
                           duration: 0.5,
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft,
                           animations: { UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController; },
                           completion: nil)
```

However, UIViewAnimationOptions does NOT have a slide-from-right animation.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why is this necessary? It seems kind of awkward. It sounds like you want to default system push transition. Why not make a navigation controller your root view controller and push and pop as necessary?

Comment: This link will help you: https://medium.com/@danielemargutti/animate-uiwindows-rootviewcontroller-transitions-2887ccf3fecc